# R read_excel from sharepoint path does not exist half of the time, other half it works

Tags: r, sharepoint

I have successfully been able to pull down an excel files from sharepoint, but half of the time I try to run the code it works and the other half it tells me path does not exist.  I can't find any rhyme or reason as to why it works sometimes and not others.  I have tried opening the site first, opening the file first, but it seems to be random.  I need the code to work consistently or I can't use R for this task.  I don't log onto sharepoint, it uses my windows authentication.  Is there a way to force it to recognize me or include a password in the read_excel command?

```
df <- read_excel('//sharepoint...', 'sheetname')
```

Comment: Had a similiar issue with our sharepoint. I solved it by using the filepath of `getwd()` while I was in the right folder, when my other path didn't work (our filepath switched between `S:\` and `\\\\sharepointname`)

Answer (score 1):

To make access to SharePoint files easy you should sync the sites from the web app to File Explorer. Addresses for these cloud resources that have been synced are commonly of the form:
C:\Users\username\My Org\My Teams Group - General\Project\My Excel.xlsx
This can create a problem when the code is run multiple users. Whilst https addresses for cloud locations may work in File Explorer they do not work directly within R packages. Users are well advised to keep track of their working directory and use relative addresses where helpful to do so, but there is another option.

Make the code user agnostic by setting the username as a variable or returning the homepath with Sys.getenv() function.

```
library(openxlsx)
username <- Sys.getenv("USERNAME")
sharepoint_address <- "/My Org/My Teams Group – General/Project/My Excel.xlsx"
df <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = paste0("C:/Users/",username,sharepoint_address), sheet = "Raw Data”)
#More elegantly
df <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = paste0(Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH"),sharepoint_address), sheet = "Raw Data”)
```